# Pygame Sprites not being destroyed when collision occurs

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on pygame project and I am trying to make a point accumulator whenever the character jumps over the obstacles? However, when I set the dokill parameter in spritecollide() to true the obstacles do not become destroyed  .I want it to become destroyed so that the obstacles(that are moving from the right to the left towards the player)  jumped over go to the end of the screen and will collide with another sprite thats off the screen, (when that collision occurs points will be accumulated). I can't even start that much if the obstacles that the player don't jump over(collide with) don't become destroyed. Thanks to anyone has any suggestions! Also the spritecollide() doesn't return a list of the sprites collided, it returns this for every single sprite that it collides with ... `[<sprites sprite(in 0 groups)>]`

```
from classyforryan import sprites
import pygame
import os
import time

pygame.init() #short for initialize does return a tuple of successful intilizaton
colors={"black":(0,0,0), "white": (255, 255, 255), "red": (255, 0, 0), "green": (0, 255, 0), "purple": (164, 66, 244), "pink" :(252, 25, 123)}
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

bg=pygame.image.load('clouds_converted.jpg')
moore=pygame.image.load("baemoore_converted.png")
jump = False
fall = False

cube = pygame.image.load("cube.png")
player=sprites(moore, 50, 544)
ob = sprites(cube, 2125, 580) #changing 580 to 580
ob1 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob2 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob3 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob4 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob5 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)

spritesgroup=pygame.sprite.Group()
spritesgroup.add(ob)
spritesgroup.add(ob1)
spritesgroup.add(ob2)
spritesgroup.add(ob3)
spritesgroup.add(ob4)
spritesgroup.add(ob5)

score=600

pygame.display.set_caption("lets play!")
gameExit = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not gameExit:
    clock.tick(40)
    timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameExit= True

    pygame.display.update()
    gameDisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    time.sleep(.05)
    player.pos()
    ob.pos()
    ob.left()
    ob1.pos()
    ob2.pos()
    ob3.pos()
    ob4.pos()
    ob5.pos()


    if(timer > 1600):
        ob1.left()
    if(timer > 2800):
        ob2.left()
    if(timer > 4000):
        ob3.left()
    if(timer > 5200):
        ob4.left()
    if(timer > 6400):
        ob5.left()

    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, spritesgroup, True)
    print blocks_hit_list
    #if (blocks_hit_list!=[]):
    #    score-=10
    #    print(score)


    #print blocks_hit_list
    #for x in blocks_hit_list:



pygame.quit() #unintiliazes pygames
quit() #this will exit out of python
```

and here are our classes

```
import pygame
import os
import time
#import panda3d
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

class ourMusic: #our music class
    def __init__(self, song):
        self.song=song #sthis is the song
    def musicUpload(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.song)
    def musicPlay(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=0.0) #assignes loops and plays music
class sprites(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, xcoor, ycoor):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=xcoor
        self.rect.y=ycoor
        self.rect.topleft = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
    def pos(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y])
    def left(self):
        dist = 7
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x - dist
```

any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: you don't have to do `self.rect.topleft = self.rect.x, self.rect.y` because pygame does it automatically.

Comment: BTW: you can do `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=xcoor, y=xcoor)` and `gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)`. Group has function `draw()` which do the same as your `pos()` method but with all elements in group.

Comment: hi thanks for the tip! And sorry would mind reiterating on this "you can do self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=xcoor, y=xcoor) and gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)

Comment: `image.get_rect(x=xcoor, y=xcoor)` gives you a Rect at position x = xcoor and y = ycoor. When blitting you can use a Rect to position the image so `gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)` is doing the same as `gameDisplay.blit(self.image, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y])` but the first one is more readable. These tips is to make your code more readable. Also, you should name your classes `Sprites` and `OurMusic` so it's easier differentiate them from functions.

Answer (score 0):

If `dokill=True` in the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` function it'll remove the sprite from all sprite groups. If you have another reference to that object outside a sprite group, it'll not be removed from the program.

You're referencing your objects (`ob = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)`) and therefore they don't disappear. To fix this problem you have to remove all references and only keep your objects in sprite groups.

Create an `update()` method in your sprite class and put the methods you want the objects to be calling every frame there. Doing so allows you to use the sprite group method `update()` which will call all sprites `update()` method.

**EDIT:** If the player collide with a single sprite it should return this `[<sprites sprite(in 0 groups)>]`. This is a list of one sprite.